# Can you make ColumnLayout not spread items apart based on the layouts size?

Tags: qml

I'm working with ColumnLayouts in QML right now and I'm finding it very annoying to have to add "Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop" to every single item I add to the Layout. Is there a way to specify in the ColumnLayout to apply "Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop" to all added items?

In addition, I noticed that that items (even after their alignment being set) are spaced out across the entire Layout (instead of pushing up against each other). Is there a way to have them push up against each other instead of evenly distributing throughout the layout?

I realize I could just manually add an empty Item as the last element and have it set to fillHeight every time I use a ColumnLayout, but I'm looking for an easier solution (do it once and forget about it).

**CustomColumnLayout.qml**

```
ColumnLayout {
    id: root
    // Do something here to make ALL items have Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
    // Also do something here to make items push up against each other, instead of have split between the layout size.
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
Window {
    width: 1000
    height: 900
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    CustomColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 200
        }
    
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 200
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As to the spacing of the items in your `ColumnLayout` that's because you explicitly define a height when you set `anchors.fill: parent`. This is the equivalent of you setting `height: parent.height`. Because you do that, Qt obeys by inserting a white space in your children so that they will expand to fill the height of your `ColumnLayout`. If you do not want that space, you should not be setting `height` and let it automatically adjust the height to cover your children.

As to applying a universal `Layout.algnment` without specifying it explicitly for each child is to create wrapper components and reuse the wrapper components rather than to build the component from scratch each time. i.e. not to subclass ColumnLayout but to subclass Rectangle. Generally, in the applications I write, when I modify the default, I tend to use an `App` prefix. In this case, I would call it `AppRectangle` which I intend to mean a subclass specialization of Rectangle that's appropriate for my App. Other ones I tend to do is `AppTextEdit` and `AppLabel`, etc. for applying default positioning, stylizing and wrap-mode for my text controls.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        //anchors.fill: parent
        width: parent.width
        AppRectangle {
            color: "blue"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 200
        }
        AppRectangle {
            color: "red"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 200
        }
    }
}

// AppRectangle.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Rectangle {
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACF3icrVExDsIwDNzziqgPSBFjtoqVgSIk5lBMG+HGIXWEEPTvtBQq2g2J2+4u9jm2rT0Fljnn0RZnYSdUrchxIGzm+trcKHIjNqYEeReyw4ow1m4w3lKPNDWuqCg06mQRtfQmgOPRvtojVx9VvdjoZd5voWDjSoSvjj0KQgpaJgeMkEycYYBX2H7ozSHC5EkFtqxYy+ViMertL6kBjn8MbUUrRJpOgtWlxtnOfz3N/BPvGQ3a0tXdsnVXobKereHE8jHSHXnRPgEG456W)

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve my problem... Rectangle was just an example, the ColumnLayout could have any number of different types added to it. I want a way to specify on the ColumnLayout level that all of its children should use "Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop".

In addition, the spacing between items in the layout still occurs in your example. I was hoping there might be some property in ColumnLayout that could be set to prevent this (instead of always adding an empty item at the end of a ColumnLayout that filled the remaining height).

Comment: The space you're talking about occurs, because your example uses `anchors.fill: parent`. If you don't want that space, you should be using `width: parent.width` i.e. let `height` follow the children content instead of forcing it to spread equally when you use `anchors.fill: parent`. The comment about subclassing, applies to all components within. If you have an App default that you want to apply universally, you should subclass all components with your app defaults.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know anchors.fill was causing that! I'd rather not make a subclass for every single component that I need to add to ColumnLayout just to add the property Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop to them... really hoping there is an alternative that can be specified in ColumnLayout... some way to apply a property to all children

Comment: Hi Rick, you'll find that over time, you will develop a programming style that helps you rapidly override the default behavior of controls. I gave you my method, perhaps you will, over time, come up with a style that suits you. e.g. assigning `property kAlignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop` than reuse that property. Everything has its own pros/cons. You'll just have to choose one that has the lesser of evils for you.